# How to create an increment table on execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how to create an increment table, so that when a procedure is executed, the table contains the same number of rows as the parameter used to execute the procedure.

For example if I perform this:

```
EXEC PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_number] 5
```

I should have a table (let's call the table 'Number') that displays the following:

```
NumberID
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I change the number in the EXEC to below:

```
EXEC PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_number] 7
```

It should output:

```
  NumberID
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
```

I don't want to use the sys.objects method as that requires using the master db.

What is the best way to perform this type of insert?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misunderstood the question,so the question is the table should be autoincremented based on parameter..

```
create proc usp_test1 
(
@n int
)
as
begin
if object_id('number','u') is not null
drop table number

create table dbo.number
(
id int
);


with cte
as
(
select 1  as n
union all
select n+1 from cte
where n<@n
)
insert into number
select * from cte c  where not exists(select 1 from number n where n.id=c.n)

end
```

You could also create table only once and comment out table creation script

Comment: What's master..spt_values? Does that require going into the master db as well?

Comment: its a one time table creation script ,there are lot of way to create numbers table ,the one i posted is just one

Comment: Is there a method for lets say I post deploy a script and whatever is the value when executing the procedure it will just create the tally/number table just like that? Just thinking of an alternative method to the one you've provided an answer for variety

Comment: i have updated one more example which doesnt materialize in database using recursive cte

Comment: Just looking at the other example, that would insert the numbers in the table would it? Just tried the first snippet from your answer and I still get a blank number table. I tried including an INSERT INTO method but error stating cannot insert explict value to IDENTITY column which is 'NumberID'

Comment: you can't insert when identity is used,you have to turn set identity options to insert,why you need identity when you are inserting based on parameter ?

Comment: Your right identity not needed Anyway. your answer worked. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have (or want) a numbers/tally table, I use a UDF to create dynamic ranges.

```
Select NumberID=cast(RetVal as int) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](1,10,1)
```

Returns

```
NumberID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,100,2)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal money)

As
Begin
    With NumbTable as (
        Select NumbFrom = @R1
        union all
        Select nf.NumbFrom + @Incr
        From NumbTable nf
        Where nf.NumbFrom < @R2
    )
    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal)

    Select NumbFrom from NumbTable Option (maxrecursion 0)

    Return
End
```

Comment: Hi John, I do prefer a tally table but good answer for those who prefer to use the UDF method

Comment: Fair enough.  Just keep in your back pocket for when you need variable ranges and increments, i.e. +12 or +0.75.   Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way would be ....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_number]
  @Number INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP (@Number) Numbers
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n + 10000*Tenthousands.n Numbers
        FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) Tenthousands(n)
    )  t
    ORDER BY Numbers

END
```